# NBug documentation

Tags: nbug

Does anyone know where to find documentation for NBug 1.1.1?

I found several broken links, including the link on the NBug website. I am unable to post to the NBug website.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the latest source, installed SandCastle and built a .chm file. You can find it here: http://tinyurl.com/c5uxyho

Comment: thank you for .chm file. I'll include it with the new release. I'm currently migrating site & source to GitHub so project it may take a bit.

Answer (score 1):

A compiled CHM is available off the GitHub [site](https://github.com/soygul/NBug/tree/master/Documentation/chm).

Don't forget to "Unblock" the RAW file when downloading to view.