# How do I add custom processing to NBug when an uncaught exception occurs?

Tags: wpf, nbug

We have started utilising NBug v1.1.1 in our WPF application and would like to include some additional information from the running application when a uncaught exception is detected.

According to documentation found in this question [NBug documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253051/nbug-documentation)
the 'NBug.Settings' class should contain a static event 'ProcessingException' but I cannot find it in the referenced assembly (included through nuget).

Is there such an event in 'NBug'? Has it been moved?

Thanks.

Comment: Weird, when I look at the codeplex source which is linked indirectly from the nuget project I can see the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that event was added in the latest source code. You can download it from codeplex and compile yourself. You can also read about that event in the XML documentation within the source code (in `NBug.Settings` class)

Comment: Ok, I just noticed that the doc says version 1.1.0.0 (1.1.2.0) which I did not notice before (fine print!).

Comment: I didn't update the NuGet package to latest version (1.1.2) as some of the new features are not tested yet. Compile and use at your own risk..

Comment: I'm assuming that this means previous versions do not support functionality to customise a report outside of the static configuration (as in 'nbug.config')?